# Рекомендуемые товары в карточке товара

Tags: php, битрикс

**Привет всем.**
  Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать рекомендуемые товары в карточке товара?
 Т.е. что бы контент менеджер при оформлении карточки товара мог добавить к нему типа, сопутствующие товары или рекомендуемые товары.
 А потом вывести все это в карточке товара во frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете в инфоблоке товаров свойство "Рекомендуемые" с типом "Привязка к элементам инфоблока". В карточке товара вставляете компонент выводящий список товаров в который через фильтр (параметр "FILTER_NAME") прокидываете ИДшники товаров, которые в созданном свойстве. Фильтр (массив с идшниками рекомендуемых товаров) инициализируете до вызова компонента выводящего рекомендуемые товары.